# How to persist multiple network interfaces across reboots on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to set up a Compute Engine VM instance on Google Cloud Platform (free trial and billing enabled) with multiple (more than 2) network interfaces that can all connect to the internet even after a reboot. Everything I have tried thus far fails after a reboot.

First, I create multiple networks:

`gcloud compute networks create vpc-1 --subnet-mode custom && gcloud compute firewall-rules create vpc-1-firewall --network vpc-1 --allow tcp:22,tcp:80,tcp:443,icmp && gcloud compute networks subnets create vpc-1-subnet --network vpc-1 --range 10.0.1.0/24 --region us-east4`

`gcloud compute networks create vpc-2 --subnet-mode custom && gcloud compute firewall-rules create vpc-2-firewall --network vpc-2 --allow tcp:22,tcp:80,tcp:443,icmp && gcloud compute networks subnets create vpc-2-subnet --network vpc-2 --range 10.0.2.0/24 --region us-east4`

`gcloud compute networks create vpc-3 --subnet-mode custom && gcloud compute firewall-rules create vpc-3-firewall --network vpc-3 --allow tcp:22,tcp:80,tcp:443,icmp && gcloud compute networks subnets create vpc-3-subnet --network vpc-3 --range 10.0.3.0/24 --region us-east4`

`gcloud compute networks create vpc-4 --subnet-mode custom && gcloud compute firewall-rules create vpc-4-firewall --network vpc-4 --allow tcp:22,tcp:80,tcp:443,icmp && gcloud compute networks subnets create vpc-4-subnet --network vpc-4 --range 10.0.4.0/24 --region us-east4`

Then, I create a VM instance with those networks:

`gcloud compute instances create test-1 --boot-disk-device-name=test-1 --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190628 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --boot-disk-size=10GB --boot-disk-type=pd-ssd --zone=us-east4-c --machine-type=n1-standard-16 --network-interface subnet=vpc-1-subnet --network-interface subnet=vpc-2-subnet --network-interface subnet=vpc-3-subnet --network-interface subnet=vpc-4-subnet --network-tier=PREMIUM --min-cpu-platform='Intel Skylake'`

So far, this works just fine. When I SSH into the VM instance, I am able to make requests to websites on the first interface (`ens4` in my case) just fine. However, other interfaces do not work even though they exist and are `UP` via `ip link show`. I then follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#configuring_policy_routing for `ens5`, `ens6`, and `ens7` with the following bash script as root with the relevant IP addresses:

```
ifconfig ens5 10.0.2.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 10.0.2.6 mtu 1460
echo "1 rt1" | tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.0.2.1 src 10.0.2.6 dev ens5 table rt1
ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev ens5 table rt1
ip rule add from 10.0.2.6/32 table rt1
ip rule add to 10.0.2.6/32 table rt1

ifconfig ens6 10.0.3.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 10.0.3.6 mtu 1460
echo "2 rt2" | tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.0.3.1 src 10.0.3.6 dev ens6 table rt2
ip route add default via 10.0.3.1 dev ens6 table rt2
ip rule add from 10.0.3.6/32 table rt2
ip rule add to 10.0.3.6/32 table rt2

ifconfig ens7 10.0.4.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 10.0.4.6 mtu 1460
echo "3 rt3" | tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 10.0.4.1 src 10.0.4.6 dev ens7 table rt3
ip route add default via 10.0.4.1 dev ens7 table rt3
ip rule add from 10.0.4.6/32 table rt3
ip rule add to 10.0.4.6/32 table rt3
```

This works! I can make requests using all network interfaces (`ens4`, `ens5`, `ens6`, and `ens7`). However, after I reboot, all network interfaces are unable to connect to any websites both before and after running the above bash script (without the first two lines of each section). If I try to run `curl https://google.com`, for example, a command that works prior to a reboot, I receive the following error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com` on any interface that I try with. Even if I reboot without ever modifying anything or running any scripts, I run into the same problem (on `ens4`, too). How can I persist (and automate, if possible) what I've accomplished across reboots?

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your context, however seems that the gcloud command to create the VM is not accurate, at least for the subnets defined earlier:

> --machine-type=n1-standard-1

Won't allow you to create a VM with more than two NICs, as per [Creating Instances with Multiple Network Interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#max-interfaces).

> --zone=us-central1-a

This will throw an error, as well. Your subnets have been created in us-east4 region.

Obviously, modifying the commands to fit the VPC and VM creation will fix that mismatch. Not big deal.

The way on how you can automate the generation of the routes at the deployment/reboot of the VM is to configure a custom metadata, creating automatically the routes every time the instance is restarted, as per [Running Startup Scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Please follow the path in GCP Console:

> Compute Engine → VM instances → Click on the instance name → EDIT → Custom Metadata → Add item

And add the following data:

```
Key=       startup-script

Value=     ip route add 10.0.2.1 src 10.0.2.6 dev ens5 table rt1

           ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev ens5 table rt1

           ip rule add from 10.0.2.6/32 table rt1

           ip rule add to 10.0.2.6/32 table rt1
```

Do the same for all additional NICs. "echo" command is not necessary since it writes a register to the "/etc/iproute2/rt_tables" file and this is persistent. However, "ip route" changes are volatile. They will dissapear after each reboot. Using the startup script will let you to run the commands at the same time that the boot starts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `create` command was indeed a typo and I have fixed the question to reflect the correct information. I have followed your directions and I still run into the same `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com` error. Even if I reboot a new VM instance as created above without modifying anything or running any scripts, I run into the same issue on all interfaces!

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem is not the additional NICs by themselves, but DNS service. Are you able to execute the CURL command but **using IP address** instead domain name? Eg. 'curl 74.125.141.94'. Also, try to ping external hosts from your VM but using IP address instead domain name. You need to isolate the issue in order to know what you need to verify.